# Trying to store invalid hexadecimal number in int variable

Tags: c, gcc, int, hex, undefined

I have a very basic doubt. I am trying to store any invalid hex number in an int variable. By invalid number i mean a number that is using alphabets that are not in `A-F` range. For example see this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%X",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

When console asks for input, I entered `G`. It gave the output as `63`. Is it just undefined behaviour or there is some logic behind this output. For most of such inputs the output is coming out as `63`. Currently working on GCC.

Comment: `scanf("%X",&a);` ==> `if (scanf("%X", &a) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: Try with `int a = 12345;` and see what happens to `a`.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Ya this time it is printing `12345` if i input any invalid hex number otherwise it prints the decimal of hex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 scanf("%X",&a);
```

`%X` will seek for hexadecimal input only. If you input `G` the directive will fail, and no assignment to `a` will happen. In this case `scanf()` returns `0`, which specifies the number of items successfully consumed.

You should check if all items were successfully consumed by checking the return value of `scanf()`:

```
if(scanf("%X",&a) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred at scanning hexadecimal input!");
}
```

---

> *"When console asks for input, I entered `G`. It gave the output as `63`. Is it just undefined behaviour or is there some logic behind this output?"*

Since `a` is uninitialized:

```
int a;
```

and there was no consumption successfully at the `scanf()` call which would have assigned a reasonable value to `a`, `a` still contains a garbage value as it is an object of the storage duration `auto`matic by default.

To print this garbage value value invokes indeed undefined behavior.

Comment: So it means `%X` will allow only hex value to be stored in variable `a`. Any non hex value will simply be ignored. Right ?

Comment: Replace "can check" with "should check".

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Did it.

Comment: @Noshiii "Any non hex value will simply be stop this `scanf("%X",&a)` and the `G` remains in `stdin` for the next input function.

Comment: @Noshiii But It´s not only that the non hex value will be ignored in a manner that the directive will seek for more input which could be a hex value. Any non hex will, as @chux already said, stop the seeking for hex values at that directive and go to the next directive (if any) or (as in this example) abort `scanf()`.

Comment: @ RobertS supports Monica Cellio so that means if i put a statement ike `scanf("%c",&b);` for some char variable b just after my first scanf(), the `G` value will automatically be stored in b?

Comment: @Noshiii Yes exactly, but what I had in mind was more something like that: `scanf("%X%c",&a,&b);`. `%X` and `%c` relate to two different directives. Nonetheless, this does not have an influence on `a` if the input is a non hex value. It will only store the inputted `G` in `b`. Thus, printing `a` is still undefined behavior if not otherwise initialized.

Comment: @ RobertS supports Monica Cellio Ok got it but now i have another doubt. Why are you using word `directive` here ?? Isn't `directive` word is used for the preprocessor functions like `#include` and `#define` ? is there some other meaning of directive here ?

Comment: @Noshiii This will help you in the understanding of the term "directive" in the context of `scanf()` under "Description", Sub-Section "*Format Control String*": https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/src/scanf.html

Comment: @Noshiii: The C standard calls the things in a format string for `scanf` “directives” because they direct `scanf` on what to do. This terminology is in C 2018 7.21.6.2 3, and directives include white-space characters, ordinary characters, and conversion specifications that begin with `%`. Preprocessor directives are also called “directives,” but there is generally no confusion between them, as context usually makes it clear which we are talking about.